# using INotifyPropertyChanged instead of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `ListView` bound to a collection, and I want the `ListView` to automatically update when an item is added to the collection. I managed to get it working using an `ObservableCollection`, but I'd rather to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead. Maybe you can give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

First, here is the (relevant part of) XAML:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Family}"> <!-- DataContext is of type Family -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Here are the relevant classes:

```
public class Family : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    private readonly IList<Member> _members;
    public IEnumerable<Member> Members { get => _members; }

    public Family(string lastName, IEnumerable<Member> members)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
        _members = members.ToList();
    }

    public void AddMember(string name)
    {
        var member = new Member { FirstName = name };
        _members.Add(member);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Members));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public class Member
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

If I use this code and call `AddMember` somewhere, it will not update the ListView GUI. I don't see why not, because `AddMember` calls `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Members))`, and `Members` is what the `ListView` is bound to. So it should get notified about the change.

**So what am I doing wrong?**

If I change `IList<Member> _members` into `ObservableCollection<Member> _members` and `_members = members.ToList()` into `_members = new ObservableCollection<Member>(members)` accordingly, it works as expected.

Comment: "it should get notified about the change" - it gets notified, then compares current and previous value, finds them equal and does nothing. you can implement INotifyCollectionChanged in your class. reconstructing all items after only one was added can be costly

Comment: @ASh can you point me to some links explaining what you hinted to (or explain yourself)? About that comparison: What is compared and when? Why are previous and current value equal? (Sure they are equal reference-wise, but the content changed.) What do you mean by reconstructing all items?

Comment: after notification for `Members` property, current value of ItemsSource and new value of Members are compared. they are the same reference to _members list. collection content doesn't matter

Comment: when you assign new Itemssource, ListView will delete all items, and then create new items for elements of new collection (reconstruct)

Comment: When you say "*it works as expected*" with ObservableCollection, why not just stick with that standard approach? It is what you would typically do. Anythings else looks awkward.

Comment: There should be a readonly property `public ObservableCollection<Member> Members { get; }` which is initialized as `Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>(members)`. You never need to fire the PropertyChanged event for Members.

Answer (score 1):

After adding an item to the `_members` collection, the **reference** returned by `Members` is **still the same**. The `Equals` method of collections will usually compare references, not items. Consequently, the binding will not detect a change and does not reevaluate the property.

If you want to get this to work, you could do one of the following:

- Assign `null` temporarily, raise property changed, reassign the collection and raise property changed again, so the binding detects a changed reference (thanks to @Ash).

  ```
  public void AddMember(string name)
  {
     var member = new Member { FirstName = name };
     _members.Add(member);

     var members = _members;
     _members = null;
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Members));

     _members = members;
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Members));
  }
  ```
- Naive approach, recreate the collection when you add a member, e.g:

  ```
  public void AddMember(string name)
  {
     var member = new Member { FirstName = name };
     _members = _members.ToList();
     _members.Add(member);
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Members));
  }
  ```

  This is costly due to lots of unnecessary allocations, don't do it.

As you can see, both approaches have their downsides, either firing additional property changed notifications or unnecessary allocations which will additionally cause the `ListView` to **remove and recreate all** of its items each time. This is why there is an `ObservableCollection<T>` type that implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0), which allows notifying added and removed items specifically, as well as other operations.

Comment: "If you want to get this to work, you would need to recreate the collection each time" - not at all. just reset *property* to null, raise notification, reassign same collection to property, raise notification again. no memory allocations needed

Comment: @ASh Thank you very much, I did not think about that. There was a typo, the link was correct, but not the name, of course it is _ INotifyCollectionChanged_.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is good that you decided that a Family is not an ObservableCollection. After all, you can do a lot of things with ObservableCollections that can't be done in Families. For instance: what would Replace(Member) mean in the context of a family?

The problem is, that you forgot to implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0).
With this interface you can notify others that you added an element (and moved, and deleted, etc.)

```
public class Family : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    ...
```

Because you also have to notify if elements are moved / deleted / etc. This will cost some development effort if your family can do more than just Add.

Therefore it might be a good idea to change your
`private readonly IList<Member> _members;`
into an `ObservableCollection<Member>`, and implement the interface via this ObservableCollection.

```
class Family : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

private readonly ObservableCollection<Member> members;

public IEnumerable<Member> Members => this.members;

public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
{
    add => this.members.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.CollectinChanged += value;
    remove => this.members.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.CollectinChanged -= value;
}
```

Now your Add / Remove / Replace / Move / etc methods will be one-liners; the appropriate event will be raised.

```
public void Add(Member member)
{
    this.members.Add(member);
}

public void Remove(Member member)
{
    this.members.Remove(member);
}
```

Not sure if you need methods to Move and Replace family Members, but even if you need to, they will also be one-liner calls to the corresponding ObservableCollection method

You have completely hidden that you are using an `ObservableCollection<Member>`, so if in future you need to completely get rid of the ObservableCollection, your users won't have to change, as long as you promise to implement the interfaces.